# Count number of distinct locations served by the same vehicle postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a table similar to the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE movements (
    "id" integer,
    "date" timestamp with time zone,
    "origin" character varying(255),
    "destination" character varying(255),
    "vehicle" character varying(255)   
);

INSERT INTO movements (id,date,origin,destination,vehicle)
 VALUES (1, '2017-11-01 00:00:00+00', 'loc_A', 'loc_B', 'V1'),
    (2, '2017-11-01 00:00:00+00', 'loc_C', 'loc_B', 'V1'),
    (3, '2017-11-01 00:00:00+00', 'loc_D', 'loc_B', 'V1'),
    (4, '2017-11-02 00:00:00+00', 'loc_E', 'loc_B', 'V1'),
    (5, '2017-11-02 00:00:00+00', 'loc_A', 'loc_B', 'V2'),
    (6, '2017-11-02 00:00:00+00', 'loc_F', 'loc_B', 'V2');
```

How can I count the number of distinct origin locations that have used the same vehicles for each origin location and the mean and maximum number of origin locations that used the same vehicle per origin location on the same day?

In this case would be an output like

```
location, total, daily_mean, daily_max
loc_A   ,     4,        1.5,        2
loc_C   ,     3,          2,        2
loc_D   ,     3,          2,        2
loc_E   ,     3,          0,        0
loc_F   ,     1,          1,        1
```

Comment: I only see two vehicles for loc_A as the origin (V1 at 2017-11-01 and V2 at 2017-11-02) - where does the total of 4 come from in your expected output? Similar for loc_C, loc_D and loc_E - I can see only one vehicle, not 3.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What I want to know is the number of origin locations that use the same vehicle that has been used by each origin location. loc_A used vehicle V1 and V2 that has been used in loc_C, loc_D and loc_E (V1) and loc_F (V2)

Comment: I still don't understand it.

Comment: Maybe a diferent example that would apply to the same problem and is probably easier to understand could be the number of different people (instead of locations) that used the same uber car. Person A used car V1 that was used by 3 other persons and car V2 that was used by another.

Comment: maybe the "same vehicle" in the title doesn't help, my apologies for that. "same vehicles" would probably be better. Using the last example, so you can understand better, let's say person A has an infectious disease that can be transmitted by using the same uber car, then it could have transmitted the disease to 4 other persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, I think the below should work. It uses a self join in order to calculate the stats by day in a common table expression and then aggregates over the days in order to get the desired columns. To get the overall list we unnest the location lists for the individual days and then combine them into an array again, which may not be ideal compared to using a subquery on the base table, but hopefully suffices:

```
with day_values as (
    select m.origin, m.date
   , count(distinct m2.origin) as locations_with_shared_vehicle
   , array_agg(distinct m2.origin) as location_list
  from movements m
  join movements m2
   on m2.vehicle = m.vehicle
   and m2.date = m.date
   and m2.origin <> m.origin
  group by m.origin, m.date )

select t.origin as location
 , array_length( (select array( SELECT DISTINCT unnest(t2.location_list)  from day_values t2 WHERE t2.origin = t.origin) ), 1) AS total_locations
, avg(locations_with_shared_vehicle) as daily_mean
 , max(locations_with_shared_vehicle) as daily_max
from day_values t
 group by t.origin
 order by t.origin;
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/00daa/1/0

Comment: Thanks! Was that and I might be able to work from there. Maybe I didn't manage to make the question properly, but the "total_locations" was irrespective of the day and the two others were on the same day. Anyway, thank you very much to make an effort to 1st understand the question and then to find a solution. With your help I've managed to get the result I've needed.